# asp.net returnURL page validation to avoid man in middle attack

Tags: asp.net

I've asp.net webform application. I notice that the .net framework automatically includes the name of return url if not logged in.

I would like to validate the returnURL page so that there's no external url (created by man-in-middle attack). Could anyone please suggest whether this can be achived easily out of box in asp.net 3.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're able to request and validate the querystring returnUrl when the login form is posted back to the server.

Since the login form is posted back and handled to/by itself you should not be to worried about this attack. Form data will not be send to the returnUrl.

Comment: Thanks Christian, is this possible to implement without writing any .net code but just changing configuration?